# NumPy vectorization without the use of numpy.vectorize

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I've found myself using NumPy arrays for memory management and speed of computation more and more lately, on large volumes of structured data (such as points and polygons). In doing so, there is always a situation where I need to perform some function `f(x)` on the entire array. From experience, and Googling, iterating over the array is not the way to do this, so insted a function should be vectorized and broadcast to the entire array.

Looking at the documentation for [`numpy.vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) we get this example:

```
def myfunc(a, b):
    "Return a-b if a>b, otherwise return a+b"
    if a > b:
        return a - b
    else:
        return a + b

>>> vfunc = np.vectorize(myfunc)
>>> vfunc([1, 2, 3, 4], 2)
array([3, 4, 1, 2])
```

And per the docs it really just creates a for loop so it doesnt access the lower C loops for truly vectorized operations (either in BLAS or SIMD). So that got me wondering, if the above is "vectorized", what is this?:

```
def myfunc_2(a, b):
    cond = a > b

    a[cond] -= b
    a[~cond] += b

    return a

>>> myfunc_2(np.array([1, 2, 3, 4], 2))
array([3, 4, 1, 2])
```

Or even this:

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b = 2
>>> np.where(a > b, a - b, a + b)
array([3, 4, 1, 2])
```

So I ran some tests on these, what I believe to be comparable examples:

```
>>> arr = np.random.randint(200, size=(1000000,))
>>> setup = 'from __main__ import vfunc, arr'
>>> timeit('vfunc(arr, 50)', setup=setup, number=1)
0.60175449999997
>>> arr = np.random.randint(200, size=(1000000,))
>>> setup = 'from __main__ import myfunc_2, arr'
>>> timeit('myfunc_2(arr, 50)', setup=setup, number=1)
0.07464979999997468
>>> arr = np.random.randint(200, size=(1000000,))
>>> setup = 'from __main__ import myfunc_3, arr'
>>> timeit('myfunc_3(arr, 50)', setup=setup, number=1)
0.0222587000000658
```

And with larger run windows:

```
>>> arr = np.random.randint(200, size=(1000000,))
>>> setup = 'from __main__ import vfunc, arr'
>>> timeit('vfunc(arr, 50)', setup=setup, number=1000)
621.5853878000003
>>> arr = np.random.randint(200, size=(1000000,))
>>> setup = 'from __main__ import myfunc_2, arr'
>>> timeit('myfunc_2(arr, 50)', setup=setup, number=1000)
98.19819199999984
>>> arr = np.random.randint(200, size=(1000000,))
>>> setup = 'from __main__ import myfunc_3, arr'
>>> timeit('myfunc_3(arr, 50)', setup=setup, number=1000)
26.128515100000186
```

Clearly the other options are major improvements over using `numpy.vectorize`. This leads me to wonder several things about why anybody would use `numpy.vectorize` at all if you can write what appear to be "purely vectorized" functions or use battery provided functions like `numpy.where`.

Now for the questions:

1. What are the requirements to say a function is "vectorized" if not converted via `numpy.vectorize`? Just broadcastable in its entirety?
2. How does NumPy determine if a function is "vectorized"/broadcastable?
3. Why isn't this form of vectorization documented anywhere? (i.e., why doesn't NumPy have a "How to write a vectorized function" page?

Comment: My personal definition is that code is vectorized when the array is handed off to a C/FORTRAN function which handles all or almost all of the operations. I don't think there's a formal definition and I don't know what the origin of the term is, although I'd be interested in that piece of history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"vectorization" can mean be different things depending on context.  Use of low level C code with BLAS or SIMD is just one.

In physics 101, a vector represents a point or velocity whose numeric representation can vary with coordinate system.  Thus I think of "vectorization", broadly speaking, as performing math operations on the "whole" array, without explicit control over numerical elements.

`numpy` basically adds a `ndarray` class to python.  It has a large number of methods (and operators and `ufunc`) that do indexing and math in compiled code (not necessarily using  processor specific SIMD).  The big gain in speed, relative to Python level iteration, is the use of compiled code optimized for the `ndarray` data structure.  Python level iteration (interpreted code) on arrays is actually slower than on equivalent lists.

I don't think `numpy` formally defines "vectorization".  There isn't a "vector" class.  I haven't searched the documentation for those terms. Here, and possibly on other forums, it just means, writing code that makes optimal use of `ndarray` methods.  Generally that means avoiding python level iteration.

`np.vectorize` is a tool for applying arrays to functions that only accept scalar inputs.  It doesn't not compile or otherwise "look inside" that function.  But it does accept and apply arguments in a fully `broadcasted` sense, such as in:

```
In [162]: vfunc(np.arange(3)[:,None],np.arange(4))
Out[162]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [2, 1, 4, 5]])
```

Speedwise `np.vectorize` is slower than the equivalent list comprehension, at least for smaller sample cases.  Recent testing shows that it scales better, so for large inputs it may be better.  But still the performance is nothing like your `myfunc_2`.

`myfunc` is not "vectorized" simply because expressions like `if a > b` do not work with arrays.

`np.where(a > b, a - b, a + b)` is "vectorized" because all arguments to the `where` work with arrays, and `where` itself uses them with full `broadcasting` powers.

```
In [163]: a,b = np.arange(3)[:,None], np.arange(4)
In [164]: np.where(a>b, a-b, a+b)
Out[164]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [2, 1, 4, 5]])
```

`myfunc_2` is "vectorized", at least in `a`:

```
In [168]: myfunc_2(a,2)
Out[168]: 
array([[4],
       [1],
       [2]])
```

It does not work when `b` is array; it's trickier to match the `a[cond]` shape with anything but a scalar:

```
In [169]: myfunc_2(a,b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [169] in <cell line: 1>
    myfunc_2(a,b)
  Input In [159] in myfunc_2
    a[cond] -= b
IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 1; dimension is 1 but corresponding boolean dimension is 4
```

===

- What are the requirements to say a function is "vectorized" if not converted via numpy.vectorize? Just broadcastable in its entirety?

In your examples, `my_func` is not "vectorized" because it only works with scalars.  `vfunc` is full "vectorized", but not faster.  `where` is also "vectorized" and (probably) faster, though this may be scale dependent.  `my_func2` is only "vectorized" in `a`.

- How does NumPy determine if a function is "vectorized"/broadcastable?

`numpy` doesn't determine anything like this.  `numpy` is a `ndarray` class with many methods.  It's just the use of those methods that makes a block of code "vectorized".

- Why isn't this form of vectorization documented anywhere? (i.e., why doesn't NumPy have a "How to write a vectorized function" page?

Keep in mind the distinction between "vectorization" as a performance strategy, and the basic idea of operating on whole arrays.

Comment: "*In physics 101, a vector represents a point or velocity whose numeric representation can vary with coordinate system*", it's more about the idea [a 1D matrix is called a vector](https://www.statlect.com/matrix-algebra/vectors-and-matrices). A vector is seen as a list of scalars in the context of operator vectorization. This is this idea behind [SIMD instructions](http://ftp.cvut.cz/kernel/people/geoff/cell/ps3-linux-docs/CellProgrammingTutorial/BasicsOfSIMDProgramming.html) which is a vectorization technique used in modern GPUs.

Comment: @mins, your link says a `vector` is a matrix (2d) with 1 row or 1 column..  People run into problems when they try to apply strict linear algebra concepts to `numpy`.  I was trying to describe "vectorization" as a concept that applies to numpy arrays of any dimension.  We were doing this in Python/numpy long before GPUs and SIMD were available at the consumer level.

Answer (score 2):

### Vectorize Documentation

The documentation provides a great example in `def mypolyval(p, x):`: there's no good way to write that as a `where` condition or using simple logic.

```py
def mypolyval(p, x):
    _p = list(p)
    res = _p.pop(0)
    while _p:
        res = res*x + _p.pop(0)
    return res

vpolyval = np.vectorize(mypolyval, excluded=['p'])
vpolyval(p=[1, 2, 3], x=[0, 1])
array([3, 6])
```

That is, `np.vectorize` is clearly what the reference documentation states: convenience to write code in the same fashion even without the performance benefits.

And as for the documentation telling you how to write vectorized code, it does though in the relevant [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). It says in the documentation what you mentioned above:

> The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.

Remember: the documentation is an API reference guide with some additional caveats: it's not a NumPy tutorial.

### UFunc Documentation

The appropriate reference [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html) and [glossary](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/glossary.html#term-vectorization) document this clearly:

> A universal function (or ufunc for short) is a function that operates on ndarrays in an element-by-element fashion, supporting array broadcasting, type casting, and several other standard features. That is, a ufunc is a “vectorized” wrapper for a function that takes a fixed number of specific inputs and produces a fixed number of specific outputs. For detailed information on universal functions, see Universal functions (ufunc) basics.

> NumPy hands off array processing to C, where looping and computation are much faster than in Python. To exploit this, programmers using NumPy eliminate Python loops in favor of array-to-array operations. vectorization can refer both to the C offloading and to structuring NumPy code to leverage it.

### Summary

Simply put, `np.vectorize` is for code legibility so you can write similar code to actually vectorized ufuncs. It is not for performance, but there are times when you have no good alternative.

Comment: It is probably just unfortunate naming. Perhaps if the function was called "loopify" or something would have created less confusion with ufunc vectorization.

Comment: @norok2 Yeah, the one issue is backwards compatibility, and also naming can be quite hard. Since vectorize is used in codebases extensively, you can't just remove it, at least without a major version change, which NumPy has wisely avoided since it is a core library for so many other programs.