# How do I vectorize a function in python or numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

For instance, in Julia language, a function can easily be vectorized as shown

```
function circumference_of_circle(r)
    return 2*π * r
end

a = collect([i for i=1:200])
circumference_of_circle.(a) # easy vactorization using just (.)
```

Although I like Julia very much, it has not matured like Python.

Is there a similar vectorization technique in the Python function?

Comment: You could look up `jax`'s [`vmap`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/quickstart.html#auto-vectorization-with-vmap) for a similar functionality, `numpy`'s vectorization is a different concept.

Answer (score 3):

```
In [1]: def foo(r):
   ...:     return 2*np.pi * r
   ...: 
In [2]: arr = np.arange(5)
In [3]: foo(arr)
Out[3]: array([ 0.        ,  6.28318531, 12.56637061, 18.84955592, 25.13274123])
```

All operations in your function work with `numpy` arrays.  There's no need to do anything special.

If your function only works with scalar arguments, "vectorizing" becomes trickier, especially if you are seeking compiled performance.

Have you spent much time reading the `numpy` basics?  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/absolute_beginners.html

===

I don't know `julia`, but this code

```
function _collect(::Type{T}, itr, isz::SizeUnknown) where T
    a = Vector{T}()
    for x in itr
        push!(a, x)
    end
    return a
end
```

looks a lot like

```
def foo(func, arr):
    alist = []
    for i in arr:
         alist.append(func(i))
    return alist # or np.array(alist)
```

or equivalently the list comprehension proposed in the other answer.

or `list(map(func, arr))`

Comment: Thanks. I think my question was oversimplified. I am looking for ways to vectorize non-NumPy elements. For instance, "a" in Julia can be any element (even functions) or the vectorizing function can be very complicated. Can there be equivalence in Python?  Thanks. I am choosing not to edit my original question.

Comment: Read my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71904004/numpy-vectorization-without-the-use-of-numpy-vectorize/71914288#71914288 for more on "vectorization"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Julia or vectorization of functions, but if I'm understanding correctly, I believe in Python there are a few ways to do this. The plain-jane python way is using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

An example using your circumference function would be:

```
def circumference_of_circle(r):
    return 2 * 3.14152 * r

circles = [[x, circumference_of_circle(x)] for x in range(1,201)]

print(circles)
```

`circles` list will contain inner lists that have both the radius (generated by the `range()` function) as well as its circumference. Like Julia function vectorization, python list comprehension is just short-hand for loops, but they take in a list object and return a list object, so they are very handy.

Comment: @BigBen I was hoping folks would pile on with numpy and other ways to pull this off in python :)

Comment: can it have a similar performance as NumPy or Julia vactorizations using list comprehension?

Comment: @stochasticlearner My very very limited understanding of julia's vectorization is that it's just short hand for a for loop with an array push so they should be similar (within the confines/performance of Python and Julia).

Answer (score 0):

Your function contains only simple math. Python's `numpy` and `pandas` modules are designed in ways that allow such operations to be performed on them.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
def circumference_of_circle(r):
    return 2 * np.pi * r
print(circumference_of_circle(a)) # array([ 6.28318531, 12.56637061, 18.84955592, 25.13274123])
```

More complicated functions cannot be applied directly to an array. You may be able to rewrite the function in a vectorized way, for example using [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for conditions that would be represented by an `if` block within a normal function.

If this isn't an option, or speed is not a major concern, then you can iterate over the list using a list comprehension `[func(v) for v in arr]`, numpy's [`vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html), pandas's [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). You can sometimes optimize these approaches by [pre-compiling parts of the code](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/enhancingperf.html).